# Count rows per group in the same table and show 0 in the groups where there are no rows

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I am trying to plot a count of rows per group. For some groups, there are 0 rows. In this case, I would like the sql statement (postgresql) to return 0 instead of not showing the group at all. For now, my statement (below) does not return the groups in which the WHERE condition yields 0 rows.

```
SELECT
    gb_timestamp_col::DATE,
    COUNT(*) AS count_
FROM my_table
WHERE some_float_col < 0 
GROUP BY gb_timestamp_col::DATE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the condition to a [`filter`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) clause: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/GKk1VvLg)

```sql
SELECT gb_timestamp_col::DATE,
       COUNT(*)filter(WHERE some_float_col < 0) AS count_
FROM my_table
GROUP BY gb_timestamp_col::DATE
```

| gb_timestamp_col | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-26 | 4 |
| 2023-10-27 | 3 |
| 2023-10-30 | 3 |
| 2023-10-29 | 4 |
| 2023-10-31 | 0 |
| 2023-10-25 | 1 |
| 2023-10-28 | 4 |
| 2023-10-24 | 0 |

Sample generator and original query on the same sample:

```sql
select setseed(0.1);--stabilise random between tests

create table my_table as 
select generate_series(now(),
                       now()+'1 week',
                       '4 hours'::interval) gb_timestamp_col, 
       random()*10-5 as some_float_col;


SELECT
    gb_timestamp_col::DATE,
    COUNT(*) AS count_
FROM my_table
WHERE some_float_col < 0 
GROUP BY gb_timestamp_col::DATE
```

| gb_timestamp_col | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-26 | 4 |
| 2023-10-27 | 3 |
| 2023-10-30 | 3 |
| 2023-10-29 | 4 |
| 2023-10-25 | 1 |
| 2023-10-28 | 4 |

Comment: oh waw! seems to work, what is this filter thing ???

Comment: I added a link to the doc. It just filters out rows after groups are established, not before. You've probably seen it done in a less efficient and standard-compliant form of `sum(case when condition then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: and also the demo link, good to know about such sites